# Access oracle database with sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Friends,
I have the following parameters but I am not able to access my database through sqlplus.

User:jeocall
Senha: jeocallFFM#01!
IP(host): 10.0.100.38
Port: 1521
database: jEOCALL_PDB3_DEV
Services: jeocall_pdb3_dev.gabprivate10032.gablan.oraclevcn.com

```
sqlplus: jeocall/jeocallFFM#01!@10.0.100.38:1521/Jeocall_pdb3_dev.gabprivate10032.gablan.oraclevcn.com
```

ERROR:
ERROR:
ORA-12637: Packet receive failed

Comment: Which version of client and database? [Maybe this?](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2662778_1.html) Otherwise could perhaps look at [this](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2823379_1.html) - it could be a firewall blocking/dropping it.

Comment: This is a 19c client?  If so, check MOS note 2662778.1